# Problem with opening a named pipe

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes

I've run into a problem while trying to send data through pipes, to be more exact: i do not get non-null file descriptors for pipe.
Here is the code for creation of the pipe:

```
//PIPE is defined as a "/tmp/my.fifo"
umask(0);
...
mknod(PIPE,S_IFIFO,0);
...
p=fopen(PIPE,"w");
if (p)
{
    //fprintf(p,"some message");
    fclose(p);
}
else
    printf("Could not open the pipe\n");
```

Here is the code for reading from the pipe:

```
cos_pipe = fopen(PIPE,"r");
if (cos_pipe)
{
    fgets(buffer,80,cos_pipe);
    ...
    fclose(cos_pipe);
}
else
{
    printf("Couldn't open the pipe\n");
    usleep(300000);
}
```

Code is compiled into two different bineries that i launch separately. All the output i get is "Couldn't open the pipe".

On somewhat related note: should the program that created pipe delete it later?

Comment: Why not use [`mkfifo`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo) instead of `mknod`?

Comment: Checked strerror(errno): it's Permission denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mode` argument requires permissions too. Use `S_IFIFO|S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR`.

Consider using the `mkfifo` function instead:

```
mkfifo(PIPE,S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR)
```

You should remove the pipe when you are done using it. Also, what happens if more than one instance of your program is running at once - you're using a fixed name for the pipe.

Comment: Every program creates itself a .pid file with process identificator it recieves when  it turns into a daemon. Every other instance checks for existence of that file and doesn't continue if there is one.

Comment: Well, since your program isn't run as root (how do I know? because if it was you wouldn't have got the error), what if two users want to run it?

Comment: That's the question i'd like an answer to. )
When i've run both programs from root, the data went through succesfully

Comment: You might want to use UNIX domain sockets here